# I just want to know which one is the best choice. - the verb 'end up' and 'risk'

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm writting something.

> 1. Sometimes, I make a dirty joke even though I know I could risk the relationship being done.
> 2. Sometimes, I make a dirty joke even though I know I could risk the relationship being finished.
> 3. Sometimes, I make a dirty joke even though I know I could risk me ending up losing the person.

And I'd just want to know which one is the best choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, as a native U.S. English speaker, all of the examples sound a little awkward. I think the following sound better:

> Sometimes, I make a dirty joke even though I know I risk ending the relationship.

or

> Sometimes, I make a dirty joke even though I know I risk terminating the relationship.

or less drastically

> Sometimes, I make a dirty joke even though I know I risk damaging the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 both sound natural, but I would suggest:

"Sometimes, I make a dirty joke even though I know I could risk losing the relationship."

or even:

"Sometimes I make a dirty joke even though I know I could lose the relationship."